# Keep multiple infinite processes alive in Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

In my app, I am having 4 processes of a function with python multiprocessing, which they are consuming from a Message Queue and do some computations on them. like this for example:

```
def run():
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
          [executor.submit(some_func()) for _ in range(4)]
```

but in my case sometimes a number of them get killed.

How I can make sure that I will have 4 of them running for ever? So if one of them dies, it get restarted.

Comment: Read the documentation - there’s an execption raised when a process dies ‘abruptly’ which should allow you to start another one https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html?highlight=processpoolexecutor#concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what your code does but if you use nodejs npm called `forever` you can run a script forever, even if it dies the forever will automatically restarts it also keeps the logs.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever

You can run a python script with forever like this

```
forever start -c python my_script.py
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm using in this in production application ( in django app ), I don't think this could help.

Comment: You can execute external commands inside any application using the `os` module like `os.system("forever start -c python my_script.py")`. That's all I know.

Answer (score 0):

for starting the threads you would use the following:

```
import threading

t1 = threading.Threa(target=run)
t2 = threading.Threa(target=run)
t3 = threading.Threa(target=run)
t4 = threading.Threa(target=run)
```

but to keep them up and running in case one dies, I'm not so sure on how to do that, sorry

Answer (score 0):

If you code a try-except block inside `some_func()`, just put a global flag inside the exception to communicate the other processes that they have to die. I suppose that, `some_func()` has a `while True:` inside, so instead of that, put a `while flag:` block.

```py
kill_process_flag = False
def some_func():
    try:
        while not kill_process_flag:
            ...
    except Exception:
        kill_process_flag = True
```

The other processes will end at the end of an iteration.